# How to add a "Running" indicator to title bar in Slideshow presentation mode?

Tags: front-end, dynamic, notebooks, customization, slideshows

When in presentation mode a Slideshow notebook's cells are hidden. This is good to have when presenting. However, if you have some cells in your presentation that take more than a few seconds to execute it would be useful to have some indicator in title bar that shows when a cell is running.  This would be particularly useful in full-screen mode.

I am thinking of having the same little orange disk that appears on the *Mathematica* icon when it is running to appear in the right-hand side of title bar of the presentation when it is running a cell.

I know exceptionally little about front-end tokens/programming.  I believe I need to use [`EvaluationNotebook`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EvaluationNotebook.html) and somehow with [`SetOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetOptions.html) place a [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/<code>Dynamic.html) in the title bar that checks some built-in variable to see if the notebook is executing.  I had a look withNames["$*"]` but nothing jumped out as being the current one to use.

I found [`WindowTitle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WindowTitle.html).

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowTitle -> "test"]
```

But it seems to only take strings as the following inserts `$Failed` into the window title.

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowTitle -> Graphics[Disk[]]]
```

There appears to be a way to do this because there is a menu drop-down in the title bar when in presentation mode.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand the little orange disk idea in context of full screen mode.

Comment: @Kuba In version 11.0.1 on Windows 8.1 there is a little orange disk that appears on the notebook's *Mathematica* icon in the taskbar when code is running for a while.  I was hoping to get something similar to show in the titlebar when in presentation mode.

Comment: But the taskbar isn't visible when the slide show is in full screen mode, right?

Comment: @Kuba Correct.  That is why I want something similar in the titlebar of the slideshow in presentation mode.  The presentation mode titlebar is different from the notebook mode titlebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have some more complex ideas in mind but this is quite nice and short:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], {
  CellProlog :> SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], ShowCellBracket -> True],
  CellEpilog :> SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], ShowCellBracket -> Inherited]
  }
]
```

So it will show bracket when you evaluate cell and switch it back when it is over.

Comment: A very good idea.  I would love to see some of your other ideas.

Comment: @Edmund then keep your fingers crossed for my free time and motivation to be in phase some time during weekend :)

Comment: How do I restrict this to only Input cells? Currently this runs for both Input and Output cells. When it runs on the Output cells an error is printed; `The specified setting for the option ShowCellBracket cannot be used.`. I have put the `SetOptions` code in the *Cell Options | Evaluation Options* section of the *Options Inspector* for the slideshow notebook.

Comment: @Edmund what do you mean by `runs on the Output cells`? p.s. you can try with "Input" in private stylesheet. Haven't tried that, will do later.

Comment: When in presentation mode I run a cell that takes 30 secs or so.  The cell bracket shows up for the input cell. When the Output cell is created I error message is printed.  Actually it could either be the Output cell or the  `CellEpilog` running on the Input cell that is triggering the error.

Comment: @Edmund Sorry, didn't check more during weekend. I can't reproduce the message either. P.s. my other ideas were based on similar approach, to add a ProgressInidicator to DockedCells by CellProlog and delete it with CellEpilog.

Comment: Oh, that is interesting. RStudio has something like that ([image](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/images/notebook-longrunning.png) from [here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebooks.html)). However, it progresses as each line of code in the block progresses.